# React-native "Value for value cannot be cast from string to double"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I started my studies recently on react-native, I had a doubt about this method.
'Alert.alert (' randomNumber ');'

when trying to display a variable of type int / float, I get the following error. "react native value for value can not be cast from string to double".

To solve this, I made the conversion from int / float to string before trying to display, but I would like to understand why the error ... complete code below.

```
    /* eslint-disable arrow-body-style */

import { View, Button, Text, AppRegistry, Alert } from 'react-native';

const React = require('react');

const gerarNumero = () => {
    let numeroRandomico = Math.random();
    numeroRandomico = Math.floor(numeroRandomico * 10);
    numeroRandomico = String(numeroRandomico);
    Alert.alert(numeroRandomico);
};

const App = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Button title="Gerar um número randômico" onPress={gerarNumero} />
            <Text>Meu primeiro app </Text>
        </View>
    );
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('app2', () => App);
```

Comment: out of curiosity, why are you casting it to a `string` instead of printing the `number` directly?

Comment: When trying to use directly as int, I get this error "Value for value can not be cast from string to double".

Comment: Finally it understands the error, when the method call is made as follows 'Alert.alert ()', the component only accepts strings, but if it calls the method directly as 'alert ()' only, it is possible to pass int and float.